# Etsy Open API v3 with PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, etsy

I have a Etsy / PHP app that I haven't touched in a couple of years, and now I need to move it to v3 of Etsy's API. This requires that I implement OAuth2.

I would like to know if I need to redo the authentication from scratch, or if I can use the same credentials I created originally with OAuth 1 without having to re-authenticate. (I have oauth consumer key, oauth consumer secret, access token, and access secret.)

The code at https://developer.etsy.com/documentation/tutorials/listings/ looks straightforward enough, but without digging back through the authentication documentation, I can't tell if I can use my existing values for the x-api-key and for the bearer token. Also, does the bearer token have to be hashed or encrypted?

Comment: What is old version of etsy api? if its v2 then you can follow this migration documentation https://developer.etsy.com/documentation/migration/index

Comment: It is v2, and I had reviewed that documentation. But I didn't find it very clear in terms of populating the x-api-key and the bearer token. I suspect that's because I can't use the OAuth1.0 tokens in an OAuth2.0 application, but I'm not certain that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've already figured this out or not, but you should check out https://github.com/rhysnhall/etsy-php-sdk. It's a pretty complete package. I've forked it for my own use to make a few customizations but overall it's pretty good and super easy to implement.

Comment: show example usage?

Comment: thanks. it turns out oauth credentials can't be used for oauth2, so I had to redo the process. It ended up not being too complicated.